# Replace one column in matrix by > 1 columns

Tags: r, matrix, replace

How to easily replace a `(N x 1)` vector/column of a `(N x M)` matrix by a `(N x K)` matrix such that the result is a `(N x (M - 1 + K))` matrix?

**Example**:

```
a <- matrix(c(1, 3, 4, 5), nrow = 2) # (2 x 2)
b <- matrix(c(1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7), nrow = 2) # (2 x 3)
```

I now want to do something like this:

```
a[, 1, drop = FALSE] <- b # Error
```

which R does not like.

All I could think of is a two-step approach: attach `b` to `a` and subsequently delete column 1. Problem: it mixes the order the columns appear.

Basically, I want to have a simple drop in replacement. I am sure it is possible somehow.

Comment: which column(s) do you want to replace by which?

Comment: could be any column. see me @dww 's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cbind:

```
cbind(b, a[,-1])
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    5    7    4
#[2,]    3    6    7    5
```

If you need to insert in the middle of a large matrix (say, at column N), rather than one end you can use,

```
cbind(a[, 1:(N-1)], b, a[, (N+1):NCOL(a)])
```

For a generalized version that works wherever the insert is (start, middle or end) we can use

```
a <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 2) 
b <- matrix(c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100), nrow = 2) 

N <- 6 # where we want to insert
NMAX <- NCOL(a) # the largest column where we can insert

cbind(a[, 0:(N-1)], b, {if(N<NMAX) a[,(N+1):NMAX] else NULL})
```

Comment: but what if I have a (N x 100) matrix and I like to replace, say, column 76. This would again mix up the order (which could of course be corrected...but its some potentially uncenessary steps)